# In react how to call API while select dropdown value

Tags: reactjs

I need to call Get method API. While select the dropdown value. If I select dropdown options="A" value=1 that value will set to API URL "http://localhost:12345/api/GetProfile/Get_MyPostDetails?id=${inputValue}". Please share any idea in react js. Dropdown values are set manually.

This one I tried

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';

function App() {
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState('');
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

  // handle input change event
  const handleInputChange = value => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  // handle selection
  const handleChange = value => {
    setSelectedValue(value);
  }

  const category=() =>
  [

    {
        value:1,
        label:"2017"

    },
    {
        value:2,
        label:"2018"
    },
    {
         value:3,
         label:"2019"
    },
    {
        value:4,
        label:"2020"
    },
    {
        value:5,
        label:"2021"
    },
    {
        value:6,
        label:"2022"
    }



];


  // load options using API call
  const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
   
    const accessToken=user;
    fetch(`http://localhost:12345/api/GetProfile/Get_MyPostDetails?id=${inputValue}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers:{

      Accept: 'application/json',             
        Authorization: "Bearer " +accessToken 
         
    },
  
  }).then(res => res.json());
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>React-Select Async Dropdown - <a href="https://www.cluemediator.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Clue Mediator</a></h3>
      <pre>Input Value: "{inputValue}"</pre>
      <AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        value={selectedValue}
        options={category}
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        onInputChange={handleInputChange}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <pre>Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(selectedValue || [{}], null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried this one but it didn't work because I need get array of objects9multiple records) it display single records and also it display the option value from API URL I want to add it manually

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include your component code and any attempts you've tried so far.

Comment: I added it @John. It get the options from the same API and get the records using that record id.

Comment: Do you have any Idea @John. Share to me. Two days I'm Facing this Issue.